# number of print page insert in Footer on libreoffice document

Tags: printing, document, libreoffice

In LibreOffice, I have a document with only one page, and want to print the same  page 200 copies.
And want to insert in my footer the special caractere : "X / Y".

Where X = the number of curent page printed. 
And Y = the number of total printed page, in my case Y=200

So How can I insert X in the footer ?

Thank you

Comment: I suppose this will be possible only by ugly workarounds (e.g. use the mail merge wizard to create a document with 200 copies, and use current page / last page fields for numbering)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response,  I don't understand,  this wizard exist in libreoffice ?

Comment: Yes, Menu Tools -> Mail Merge Wizard.